# 300 ms delay on three.js touch events

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I'm working on a three.js project in which I am using TrackballControls to enable touch events. But I found that my code were not working properly. I also evaluated some working examples like http://threejs.org/examples/canvas_geometry_cube.html and found at start there is a small delay of 300 ms. But it do affect a lot in my project. How could I remove this 300 ms delay?

Note : I uses both single and multi touches in my project.

I went through the concept of fastclick ( https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick ), but for me it doesn't seem to support multi touch. If I'm wrong, please correct me.

Comment: 300 ms delay is a known issue in mobile applications or mobile websites. Do you test it on a mobile device?

Comment: yes...
I am testing it on an android Jellybean device...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a way... I was using touch to drag and drop an object in the scene... The actual problem was as follows... The 300 ms delay of touch events get combined to form a large delay... In order to overcome this, I gave a condition so that touch move events are taken with a delay of 300 ms... i.e if one event is taken, the next event taken will be the event after 300 ms... and its working quite fine...

Answer (score 0):

I remember hearing something about this: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=133391

According to the linked issue, in Chrome for Android the reason for the 300 ms delay is to recognize a double-tap zoom gesture. With the change made there (in October 2012), the delay will not be imposed if *the page cannot be zoomed*. So, at least in this case, what you need to do is set your page `meta viewport` options so that the page fits the device screen and doesn't zoom.

(Disclaimer: I've never tried this myself; I just heard about it once. I have no idea if this behavior is in current released Chrome for Android, and I don't know whether other mobile browsers, such as the stock Android browser, do the same.)

(Other disclaimer: I work for Google, but I don't work on Chrome, and I am not answering on behalf of Google here.)

Comment: ok kevin...
let me try on it...
but I may also need to use firefox for mozilla...